# Unable to display new metabox in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I am unable to add a new metabox. Here's my code. The metabox is intended to be added on a custom post type, the name of which is 'claws'.

The last line of the code actually appears in the source. It is not displaying even then. Highly illogical.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_admin');
function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box('claws_link','Link','random_callback','claws','normal','high');
}

function random_callback($post) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'random_linknonce' );
    // The actual fields for data entry
    // Use get_post_meta to retrieve an existing value from the database and use the value for the form
    $value = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_ID'], $key = 'claws_link', $single = true );
    echo '<label for="claws_link">';
        _e("Enter link", 'random_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="claws_link" name="claws_link" value = "'.$value.'" size="25" />';    //this html code actually comes in the source, still no metabox, dunno why
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box('claws_link','Link','random_callback','claws','normal','high');
});
```

or if you're not on php 5.3+

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_boxes');

function my_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box('claws_link','Link','random_callback','claws','normal','high');
}
```

Comment: Both don't work. Now even the last line is not being displayed.

Comment: Also, Why do you think that a difference in hooks would resolve the problem? I mean, almost every tutorial I see(including the one on wp.org) uses add_meta_boxes.

Comment: Try calling the hook outside the `my_admin()` function. Updated above. This is what I use for adding meta boxes. I also had previous trouble with `add_meta_boxes` hook in the past.